# how to count a array of specific words in a string php

Tags: php

I need to count some specific words in string`(How many times some word occurs in a string)`, How can I do it in php?

Example;

```
$words = array("woman", "murder", "rape", "female", "dowry");

$string = "A dowry deaths is a murder or suicide of a married woman caused by a dispute over her dowry.[4] In some cases, husbands and in-laws will attempt to extort a greater dowry through continuous harassment and torture which sometimes results in the wife committing suicide";
```

The first item is the bundle of some word, If this word match with below string increase its value....

Example of result like be:

```
dowry= 1;
murder =2;
women =5;
```

Comment: I just tried with substr_count , but  this count only one words at a time, I needs several words to count at a time...  http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`substr_count` — Count the number of substring occurrences

```
$string = "A dowry deaths is a murder or suicide of a married woman caused by a dispute over her dowry.[4] In some cases, husbands and in-laws will attempt to extort a greater dowry through continuous harassment and torture which sometimes results in the wife committing suicide";

$words = array("women", "murder","rape","female","dowry");

foreach($words as $word) {
   echo $word." occurance are ".substr_count($string, $word)." times <br />";
}
```

Output:

**women** occurance are **0** times

**murder** occurance are **1** times

**rape** occurance are **0** times

**female** occurance are **0** times

**dowry** occurance are **3** times

Comment: If the given string has a word say 'deathswomen' then it will return women occurance are 1 times which I think is not correct if you want to count only complete words and not just substring.

Answer (score 2):

function [`substr_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr-count.php) does what you want

```
foreach($words as $word)
  echo $word .' ' . substr_count($string, $word) . "\n";
```

result

```
women 0
murder 1
rape 0
female 0
dowry 3
```

[demo](https://eval.in/594425)

Answer (score 1):

using [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) is going to be straightforward

```
$string = 'I just ate a delicious apple, and John ate instead a banana ice cream';
$words = ['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi'];
foreach($words as $word) {
    $hashmap[$word] = substr_count($string, $word);
}
```

now `$hashmap` contains an associative array with `word => occurrences`

```
array(3) {
  ["banana"] => int(1)
  ["apple"]  => int(1)
  ["kiwi"]   => int(0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Split the string into words and then loop through the array of words and check if it is one of the words inside the $words array is the same.

```
$arrayOfString = explode(" ", $string); //splitting in between spaces will return a new array
for ($i = 1; $i <= $arrayOfString.count(); $i++) //loop through the arrayOfString array
{
    for($j = $words.count(); $j >= 1; $j--)//loop through the words array
    {
         if($arrayOfString[i] == $words[j])
         {
              echo("You have a match with: " + $words[j]); //Add your count logic here
         }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this works for you.

There are probably better ways for you to do this, but I like this logic myself.

Comment: this is not java dude